# Django: Add a new property to a model class by other properties in that class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to assign a new property, *apps*, to my **User** class by using the *is_admin* and *group* properties of the User class but I'm not sure how to do this.. this is what I'm trying:

In my models.py I have a User class with a method **assign_apps**. I'm trying to use that method to add a new property to the User class, **apps** (User.apps) by using an imported function **get_user_apps** and the *is_admin* and *group* properties

I'm pretty sure this won't work since I'll somehow have to invoke User.assign_apps()

Is there a better way to do this so that **User.apps** is calculated by **User.is_admin** and **User.group**?

```
from .helpers import get_user_apps

class User():
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)

    def assign_apps(self):
        self.apps = get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `property` decorator on a function.

```
from .helpers import get_user_apps

class User():
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def apps(self):
        return get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)
```

In the `apps` method you can then so what ever is required for the instance and refer to `self.group` and `self.is_admin` etc.

It will then appear as a property in usage:

```
user = User()
user.apps
```

By doing this you will not need to use `assign_apps` to setup the property it will just always be present. When you use `user.apps` (note it is a property not a function call) you will get the result for `get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)`

Comment: Do I have to use *return* in the method?:

    @property
    def assign_apps(self):
        self.apps = get_user_apps(self.group, self.is_admin)
        return self.apps

Comment: I have updated my answer to better reflect what happens. There is no need for the `assign_apps` method with my suggestion above. I hope that helps and clarifies what's happening for you.